# Find $a$ and $b$ such that $f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 - 28x + 15$ is divisible by $(x+3)$, etc

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Find the values of $a$ and $b$ if the polynomial $f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 - 28x + 15$ is exactly divisible by $(x+3)$ and leaves a remainder of $-60$ when $f(x)$ is  divided  by $(x-3)$. Use these values of $a$ and $b$  to find all values of $x$ for which $f(x) = 0$.

Can anyone help me with this problem? My teacher could not explain it simply.

I tried dividing $ax^3+bx^2 - 28x + 15$ by $x+3$  and everything my teacher tried to explain, I simply cannot get the answer.

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). I edited the formulas, and added a descriptive title

Answer (score 2):

The remainder theorem states that the remainder when $P(x)$ is divided by $(x-a)$ is given by $P(a)$.

Since $(x+3) = (x-(-3))$ divides $f(x)$, $f(-3) = 0$ which means that $a(-3)^3 + b(-3)^2 - 28(-3) + 15 = 0$ which will give you one equation for $a$ and $b$.

Since the remainder when $f(x)$ is divided by $(x-3)$ is $-60$, $f(3) = -60$ meaning that $a(3)^3 + b(3)^2 - 28(3) + 15 = -60$ which will give you a second equation for $a$ and $b$, and you can solve them simultaneously to get the two values.

Comment: So what second equation am I supposed to solve? (sorry I have a learning disability)

Comment: The first equation is the one you get from $f(-3) = 0$, and the second one is the one you get from $f(3) = -60$. You should get them to be $27a-9b=$something and $27a+9b=$something.

Answer (score 0):

look if $x+3$ divide $f(x)$ then $f(-3)=0$ and if the remainder is $-60$ when you divide by $x-3$ that´s $f(3)=-60$, then you get 2 equations and obtained a systems of equations, where the variables are $a$ and $b$.